How does the shape of a frequency domain function (Fourier Transformed time domain function) change when a time shift is applied in the time domain?
When there is a time shift (or delay) in the time domain on a function, the Fourier transform gets multiplied by an exponential which corresponds to a phase shift on the original frequency domain function.
I am struggling to graphically grasp how the frequency domain function has changes.
I have included an image of a bandlimited example and im looking for help understanding what happens to the shape when it is phase shifted.
Thank you so much. Hope you have a lovely day.

$S(j\omega)$ is a complex number, so it needs 2 graphs to completely draw it. Real + Imaginary part or phase and magnitude. So the Y axis in your picture isn't accurately labelled. If it's supposed to be the magnitude, the two graphs would be the same.

@Hilmar Genuine question for you, which I hope you don't take the wrong way. Do you usually read other answers? Do you upvote them if you find them adequate? I’m asking because your comment echoes my answer, which will be (albeit in my opinion) useful to the OP. As part of this community I try and upvote answers that I find useful to give confidence to the OPs that these answers are valid and trustworthy. I upvote yours a lot because, well, they’re always useful :) but this isn’t the first time I see a comment of yours that says exactly the same as a one of the provided answers, with no upvote

@Jdip: thanks for the heads up, I will be more mindful. The point of my comment was not intended as a duplicate to your answer but to call out that the notation of the OP is either sloppy or a fundamental misunderstanding about the complex nature of the spectrum. A Y axis labelled $S_t(j\omega)$ is simply wrong (and not for just nit picky reasons. I think)

That’s a fair point @Hilmar, and thank you for indulging my perhaps mis-guided rant!

Note that what you plotted is not the frequency spectrum $S_c(j\omega) =|S_c(j\omega)|e^{j\phi (\omega)}$, but the magnitude spectrum $|S_c(j\omega)|$
The shape of the magnitude spectrum is unchanged: you can see this by computing:
$$|e^{-j\omega t_d}\cdot S_c(j\omega)| =|e^{-j\omega t_d}|\cdot|S_c(j\omega)| = 1 \cdot |S_c(j\omega)|$$
The phase response is altered by a linear term:
$$\angle \left( e^{-j\omega t_d}\cdot S_c(j\omega)\right) = \angle S_c(j\omega) + \angle e^{-j\omega t_d} = \phi (\omega) - \omega t_d$$
